# Can I get code completion for an object with custom properties in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a class that takes in an Object. This Object defines a bunch of params that are needed later and these params can be basically any key:value pairs.
I instantiate the class and call `init()` with my params Object...

```
class Thing{
    props:{[key:string]:any};

    init(obj:{[key:string]:any}){
        this.props = obj;
    }
}

const thing = new Thing();
thing.init({
   propA: "HELLO WORLD",
   propB: 1
})
```

I now want to get code completion when accessing the properties. So typing `thing.props.` will prompt with `propA` and `propB`;
I can get this to work by setting an Interface like so...

```
interface Props{propA:string; propB:number;};

class Thing{
    props:Props;

    init(obj:Props){
        this.props = obj;
    }
}

const thing = new Thing();
thing.init({
   propA: "HELLO WORLD",
   propB: 1
})
```

...but is there a way to use the supplied Object as its own Interface if you see what I mean?
So that adding another property to the object eg `propC: "GOODBYE WORL"` will prompt `propC` as an autocomplete option without having to also add `propC:string;` to the Interface?

My issue is that the `Thing` class is intended to be part of a shared module and the params Object will be defined per usage.
Hope that makes sense :|

Comment: Make it a generic class and give it the prop definition when instantiating it? TypeScript probably can also then deduce the type from what is given in without explicit declaration

Comment: Do you expect to call init multiple times? If not you could set props in constructor and then have all the power of static type checking [play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gHltApgDwBcdkATGAbwG0BrHATwC4ICAnFVAXQegFdlrkAewDuyAL4A+cgChoc6MEHJmLHsAKCWACgAOPAEYhEwaDpaCdEbrACU0cmOnTH0xcoLQCSNNAC80ZBxhOG9ULRl5MwsAQW4AIgAJAFEAGRSAeWgAdXSAJRSAETiAGlk5KJ0AIW4ARmcbAG4nL3YAOgqIdvMdaKcAej7oAAECCABafB0cdQmWcxZpFrQui06KgGEgA)

Comment: This is interesting. Is there a way to work it without requiring the params to go to the constructor though?
I'm trying to mimic an existing experience in another platform so passing the params to init() rather than the constructor would be preferable. I can probably make this work though if its the only way to do it.

Comment: You can. But AFAIK type inference would not work and you'd need to manually provide generic value [play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gHltApgDwBcdkATGAbwG0BrHATwC4ICAnFVAXQegFdlrkAewDuyAL4A+cgChoc6AAceAIxCJgiloIUQAhN1gBuWfJNyUiAgAoFWnQYCU0GfNfQCSCADpb2mAF5NPzNoMWlpMOlgQWRmdyQ0aEDkHGE4BNQrB2MPdi8La3IghQBBbgByAEZygBpigCEKgCZysQdw3LQfO29fUvCAegHoAAECCABafAUcYAIpli0WaU7Ubr91hQBhcOjYgmKIJqTnYq2KgGZy0N2YuLAhDxwWBHYTlLTXtAwCOhnBABmhyaEiy0gegieLwy+WQlhsPSa7WkQ1G4ymeBmcwWS3Bj3gzy+az6vTsABEgA). Notice the first error is not captured.

Comment: The only way for this to work with `init()` the way you want would be for it to be an assertion method (which requires an annotation where you might not expect to need to put one), as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvqnQm). Does that fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It answers my question really well though it also highlights that I probably asked the wrong question or framed it in too simple a way. This has given me a lot to dig into so thanks for that. Write it up and I'll accept it for sure!